# single space issue in bing search api?

Tags: php, api, space, bing, bing-search

i am integrating bing search api into my website. i am using bing image search. its working fine for me but when i search image from website i got a one big issue. issue details is given below

```
$query= 'kamen rider site: http://p-bandai.jp/';
$query = urlencode("'$query'");
```

when i search this from bing api all correct images are came. but when i search this keyword i don't have any results. code is given below

```
$query= 'tomica disney site: http://p-bandai.jp/';
$query = urlencode("'$query'");
```

i got the issue creating place. but i dont know how to solve the issue.

issue : when i search `tomica disney site: http://p-bandai.jp/` i dont get any results. but when i search `tomica disneysite: http://p-bandai.jp/` i got the results. please give me any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any results because Bing does not have anything in index for that website and query. Check it out:
http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=tomica%20disney%20site%3Ap-bandai.jp

site: limits results to be coming only from one website. Since, in second case, you don't have a space between Disney and site:, site: constraint is not working and results returned from index of the all websites.

To summarize: Bing (and Google as well) does not have anything in index for website p-Bandai.jp for query 'tamica disney'. In second case it works only because you mistyped query and site: constraint is not actually applied.